# CSS: Sidebar fixed width with background to edge of window

Tags: html, css

Here is a quick mockup of what I am trying to create: http://aven.dk/site.png

```
                      Browser width
    [————————————————————————————————————————————————]
     ————————————————————————————————————————————————
    |      |  FLUID WIDTH CONTENT |FIXED WIDTH|      |
    |      |                      |SIDEBAR    |      |
    |      |                      |           |      |
    |      |                      |           |      |
    |      |                      |———————————|——————|
    |      |                      |           |      |
    |      |                      |           |      |
    |      |                      |           |      |
    |      |                      |           |      |
    |WHITE |  WHITE               |           |      |
     ————————————————————————————————————————————————

           [——————————————————————————————————]
             width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;
```

How will I be able to do this, can I do this with pure CSS or with some jQuery?

I want my content to be centered in the browser, 1000px wide.

My sidebar will have a fixed width floated right, its height need to be dynamic, ie I wont be able to use a background image to simulate this. The sidebar will have a dark red color, this color will also have to expand to the right side of the browser, to the edge.

So far I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/AcLLT/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;

            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            background: #eee;
        }

        .container {
            width: 1000px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .content {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            padding-right: 300px;
        }

        .content-bg {
            background: #fff;
            position: relative;
        }

        .content-bg:before {
            right: 100%;
            background: #fff;
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 9999px;
        }

        .sidebar {
            float: left;
            width: 300px;
            margin-left: -300px;

            background: #00f;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-bg">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The 1000px width should be from the starting point of the content to the edge, because your mockup is not the same as your "drawing" that you just added? EDIT: I mean the container not the content...

Comment: I just edited the "drawing" to be like my mockup.

Answer (score 0):

You might need something like this JSFiddle Link [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AcLLT/4/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-bg">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-bg">l2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        background: #eee;
    }

    .container {
        width: 100%;
        min-width:100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position:relative;
    }

    .content {
        background: #c00;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:50%;
        margin-right:-100px;
    }

    .content-bg {
        background: #f00;
        position: relative;
        width:600px;
        float:right;
    }

    .sidebar {
        background: #ccc;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:50%;
        right:0;
        margin-left:100px;
    }

    .sidebar-bg {
        background: #ddd;
        position: relative;
        width:400px;
        float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to do something about it with some **jQuery**.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-bg">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-content">
            sidebar
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html,
body {
    font: normal 1em Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 700px;
}

.content-bg {
    margin: .5em;
}

.sidebar {
    background: darkRed;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    height: 250px
}

.sidebar-content {
    margin-left: .5em;
    width: 300px;
}
```

and

**jQuery:**

```
$('.container').css({
    'padding-left': $(window).width()/2 - 500
});
$('.sidebar').css({
    'width': $(window).width() - 700 - ($(window).width()/2 - 500)
});
```

and of course here is the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2p388/1/)** for it as well.

I tested it in latest versions on windows of Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari (they stopped working on the windows version so it might not be the same on Mac), IE11 and Maxthon and everywhere was working just good.

I hope this is what you need and it works well.

**EDIT:**

You might want to try something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Fr8nK/)** in case you want something more responsive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like the sidebar's color to reach the edge of the browser aswell all the way to the right

Comment: It does. Well unfortunately if you resize the window you have to refresh the page to do it again. It is not responsive like that.

Comment: @KasperHyldalPedersen: For similar that you are trying to achieve without bootstrap or anything like that I would suggest something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fr8nK/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a solution that meets your specific criteria: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/k5c3j/

There are a lot of things that I really don't like about it though.  For one, it's dependent on javascript for styling the layout.  Mainly though, the use of pixel-based fixed width for the elements means it's not at all responsive.

You can see how ugly the results get when you are at less than 1000px in the fiddle.  Sure, you can use media queries to address that, by changing your content width and setting your sidebar to drop below the content area on the smallest devices.  Still, it's not fluid for the range of modern devices used today.  I would strongly suggest reconsidering the design and working out something that is based on a responsive grid.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* End Reset */
.wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue; 
    position: relative;
}
.main-content {
    width: 540px;
    margin: 0 30px 0;   
}
.sidebar-wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 600px;
}
.sidebar-content {
    width: 360px;
    margin: 0 30px 0;   
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main-content">
            <h1>Content Container:</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-content">
                <h2>Sidebar Container:</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.sidebar-wrapper').height($(window).height());
        $('.sidebar-wrapper').width($(window).width()-$('.sidebar-wrapper').offset().left);
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess with my design I wont be able to do this without the usage of javascript. And I would like to avoid that. My design is kinda inspired by: https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/3816/screenshots/657309/attachments/57163/snowbird_home.png

Where the sidebar will fill the right side of the browser aswell.

Comment: Assuming that you always had content in the sidebar that was at least as tall as the screen height, and if you didn't need to have your content centered on the screen this could be reworked to eliminate the javascript.  I think the design for the Snowbird site is hot, BUT, it's not responsive either.  I just think you could do a pure CSS design with the help of a framework like Bootstrap or Foundation that was just as appealing, but with the benefit of being responsive.